# Razor @if inside <script> is rejected by VS11

Tags: visual-studio, razor, syntax-highlighting, asp.net-mvc-4

Is the following markup incorrect, or is it a bug in the Razor engine in MVC4? Either way, what's the best workaround?

The entire content of **View1.cshtml** is shown. It compiles fine, but the Intellisense error highlighting is annoying. *(Included as an image so you can see how the syntax is rejected by VS11.)*

[image: Markup highlighting]

Hote that the `@:` syntax (instead of `<text></text>`) isn't accepted either.

Comment: Intellisense in VS2010 also acts weird when c# code appears inside a `<script>`. I just got over it.

Comment: Did you report the bug on MS Connect?

Comment: Have done now http://tinyurl.com/vs11error. Any workaround for the time being? Or do I have to just ignore it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little tricky to mix JavaScript with Razor. Personally, I find it easier to always separate these two guys by using either Razor `@function` or Razor custom `@helper`.

Here's a simple example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btn_clicked() {
        @generateMyJavaScript()
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='btn_clicked()'>Click on me</a>

@functions {
    private MvcHtmlString generateMyJavaScript()
    {
        string jsBuilder = string.Empty;
        if (true)
            jsBuilder = "alert('Hey!');";
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(jsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed strange behavior of the syntax highlighter too. This is not really an answer but:

- I try staying away from mixing model data into javascript. Although powerfull it is a bit spaghetti-like.
- Also I try to have as little as possible  tags in the html. I use js includes and jQuery $(document).ready(function () ...  functions inside those.
- There you can extract the JSON data from the data attributes and base javascript decisions on those.

(Wanted to write this as a comment but didn't find the way to do that, sorry for the debump)