# How can I get IntelliSense to work inside of a script tag for Razor helpers?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, intellisense

IntelliSense does not work in Visual Studio 2010 if you are inside of a `<script>` tag and try to use `@Html.`. Anyone know how to enable or fix that?

Please note: This is **not** for javascript, jQuery, or similar, IntelliSense-enabling which is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug/complexity resulting from hosting JavaScript inside the HTML editor: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/2706979-improve-the-razor-intellisense-inside-script-block

It doesn't look like it will be resolved anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick suggestion, separate JavaScript and Razor like I described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11109799/538387

Comment: @Thid - Thank you, I did not know that was even an option.